# modalviewcontroller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, modalviewcontroller

I have VideoViewController.swift and I want to play the video in secondviewcontroller like this photos(not a full screen) when I press the button

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBB4d.png]]

I try to use modal view controller but it doesn't work.. what is the problem?

This is the source code:
VideoViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class VideoViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var AVPlayerView: UIView!

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // yoon // from web
        let sampleURL = NSURL(string: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")!
        let player = AVPlayer(URL: sampleURL)


        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

        let videoWidth = 320
        let videoHeigh = 180
        let screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width
        let screenHeigh = self.view.frame.size.height

        playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(
            (screenWidth/2 - CGFloat(videoWidth/2)),
            (screenHeigh/2 - CGFloat(videoHeigh/2)),
            CGFloat(videoWidth),
            CGFloat(videoHeigh))

        AVPlayerView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)


       player.play()

        //AVPlayerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

viewController. swift

```
import UIKit
import Social
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, SideBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var AVPlayerView: UIView!

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    @IBAction func videoStream(sender: AnyObject) {


        self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
        // Cover Vertical is necessary for CurrentContext
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .CurrentContext
        // Display on top of    current UIView


        self.presentViewController(VideoViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
        //self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 200)
}
```

Comment: It seems like you are using a xib or storyboard and if you need to load from storyboard/xib you have to use the respective allocation rather than VideoViewController().

Answer (score 0):

There are several forcefully unwrapped optionals in your code. You need to make sure the outlets are set before you unwrap them. The following will play play the video in the second vc but you need to add the frame and other stuff you wanted. The first vc is fine as it is

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class VideoViewController: AVPlayerViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var AVPlayerView: UIView!

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    private func playVideo() {
        player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")!)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        playVideo() 
    } 

}
```